# What is the best AJAX library for Django?

Tags: ajax, django

Which AJAX library is the best for django and why?
Looking for one with a large database of tutorials, books and detailed documentation.
Which one is the easiest to work with?
Which one is in early development but shows great promise for the future?

Regards,
chriss

Comment: Changed the title of your question to something more relevant.

Comment: Would have been good to clarify if this is a question about javascript libraries (prototypejs, jquery, dojo...) or Django/Python libraries (dajax...)

Comment: It seems the answers around here are now highly deprecated as frameworks such as [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [Tastypie](http://tastypieapi.org/) seem to be more active and now preferred by most developers while others seem to be having problems with frameworks that are less maintained at the moment (such as [Dajax](http://dajaxproject.com/)).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I highly recommend [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/).  There are several tutorials on how to implement it.

http://lethain.com/entry/2007/dec/11/two-faced-django-part-5-jquery-ajax/

http://lethain.com/entry/2007/dec/01/using-jquery-django-autocomplete-fields/

http://vincentxu.net/minimal-ajax-in-django-with-jquery-post

**NOTE:** Microsoft also announced a while ago that jQuery would be the official client-side framework for ASP.NET MVC, so its good to know regardless of what server side framework you're using.

Comment: Note: The first two links no longer work.

Comment: The links seem to be back online.

Comment: Incidently, don't ever construct a JSON response like `"{'response_text': '"+post_text+" recieved.'}"` as in the third link. Import `json` or `simplejson` and use `dumps`!

Comment: Although jQuery is fantastic, sadly, Django has no explicit integration (outside of admin) with its forms or views.

Comment: The last link does not work any more.

Answer (score 62):

I think this may be what you're looking for: [django-dajax](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax)

Pretty well documented. Simple api. Very clean and nice. I plan on using it more in some of my projects. It's JS library agnostic, and works well with jQuery if that's your thing.

UPDATE:

Other solutions similar to dajaxice, but not standard dajax.

- https://github.com/joestump/django-ajax - Joe Stump's solution that makes it dead simple to create restful endpoints from your models.
- https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home - Similar idea, but a bit more robust. You can define the data format for your endpoints (xml vs json etc).
- https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie - Similar to piston, but I've had better luck with tastypie.

In the end they mostly work the same.

- Define/include some predefined URL routes.
- Register models/views/functions that will be used as data sources.
- Enjoy.

UDATE2:

This advice is super old. Should probably research other solutions.

Comment: I'm surprised this didn't get the vote. Looks great. Diving in now.

Comment: It's 1.5 years later now, and the project looks like it hasn't had many updates since then.  Is this still a good recommendation?

Comment: @TimSaylor I'd say DajaxIce is still a pretty solid library if this is the kind of solution you're looking for: a dead simple way to create arbitrary ajax endpoints you can consume in javascript. I personally wouldn't use the regular Dajax lib as you end up writing a lot of presentation code in your view functions.

That said there are plant of solid libraries available for creating RESTful endpoints automatically from your models (or other arbitrary data). (I'll update my answer with links).

Comment: super lib for implementing ajax in django

Comment: Note: dajax & dajaxice are not compatible with django 1.6.

Comment: @avelis Somebody has created a fork that apparently does support 1.6: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dajax-ng

Comment: The Github page for Dajax *now* says `Should I use django-dajaxice?` - `In a word, No. I created this project 4 years ago as a cool tool in order to solve one specific problem I had at that time`

Answer (score 16):

There's nothing about Django that makes any of the libraries easier or work better with the framework.  Just use the one that fits your brain the best.

Having said that, my sense is that jQuery is more popular in the Django world and is what I personally use.  Most notably, many of the apps in [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) require jQuery.  Some other shared apps and code snippets for Django:

http://www.djangosnippets.org/tags/jquery/
http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-validation/
http://code.google.com/p/django-todo/
http://code.google.com/p/donita/

Answer (score 8):

Also keep in mind that the newest Django books ([Python Web Development with Django](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132356139), [Learning Website Dev with Django](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847193358)) use jQuery in their tutorials.

Answer (score 7):

Checkout [Dajax](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax):

> **Dajax Project**
>
> Easy to use AJAX libraries for Django
>
> Fast, easy and lightweight libraries
>   to implement AJAX inside your django
>   projects. Ready to use in 5 minutes.
>
> Dajax is a powerful tool to easily and
>   super-fastly develop asynchronous
>   presentation logic in web applications
>   using python and almost no lines of JS
>   source code.
>
> It supports up to four of the most
>   popular JS frameworks: Prototype,
>   jQuery, Dojo and mootols.

Comment: After I have posted this answer I have noticed that someone already mentioned Dajax, but that answer does not describe what the library offers (and was unable to comment it)

Comment: And if you check the Github READMEs you find "Should I use django-dajax or django-dajaxice?

In a word, No. I created these projects 4 years ago as a cool tool in order to solve one specific problems I had at that time.

These days using these projects is a bad idea."

Answer (score 4):

I've successfully used jquery, YUI and Dojo on different django projects. There's nothing about any of those that made it better to use with django specifically. I agree with jpartogy that mochikit may fit django more than any other just because of the "pythonic" (twisted-like) API. It really depends on what you are looking for in an ajax framework.

Personally I like what jQuery can do with given amounts of code but the greatest challenge in writing jQuery code is making it readable.

YUI is much more verbose than other frameworks because it sets a convention for using namespaces, but there are shortcuts to write less code and it avoids trying to make javascript look like something else.

Dojo tries to make javascript look like Java and from my experience is pretty slow. It has some nice widgets and a javascript implementation of the django templating language (which is pretty useful even outside of django projects).

I personally avoid prototype and mootools because they can break other javascript code (or vice versa).

If you are new to javascript and ajax I'd recommend jQuery because it's the easiest to start with. But I don't expect any js framework to be integrated with django mostly because there's really no need for that.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to Soviut and Daniel for good answers.  Jquery is a nice framework.  Besides Pinax a couple other "big" Django applications use it: [Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) and [Review Board](http://www.review-board.org/) (which switched from another framework... mootools IIRC).

Also popular is rolling your own Javascript without using any framework, for example the Django admin.

The only other suggestion I might make is that, if you are a very experienced Pythonhead, then you might like [mochikit](http://www.mochikit.com/index.html) which comes under some criticism for being too 'pythonic'.
It seems to be the framework of choice for Turbogears but I personally haven't seen any Django projects using it.

Comment: Good answer except for the phrase about rolling your own JS.  I wouldn't call that popular, I haven't seen it in Django apps other than the Django admin, and I recommend against it.  Why bang your head against a brick wall when you don't have to?  +1 here if that's removed.

Comment: Well, I'm not saying it's a good idea :)  My javascript is weak enough that I don't have a choice so I use jquery.  I mentioned it because I did a survey of 4-5 of the sites at the top of the list at djangosites.com and found them all using custom js.

Comment: In fact even Django admin is switching to JQuery:
http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/12297

Answer (score 1):

Okay this might be subjective because the definition of 'best' can mean different to each individual. But since you are working with Django, that means you will get your hands down with Python syntax. One notable Javascript library that doesn't get exposed too much is [Mochikit](http://www.mochikit.com/). The good thing about it is it has syntax that is familiar to Python programmer (because the creator is a Python programmer). It has quite nicely written down documentation as well. TurboGears out-of-the-box supports Mochikit.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to work with AJAX in your django projects with very little setup and simple to use, my offer is:

**django-ajax** ([Github](https://github.com/yceruto/django-ajax), [Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/abalt-django-ajax))

Fast, flexible and easy to use AJAX libraries for django projects. Contains ajax decorator, ajax middleware, shortcuts and more.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "Best AJAX Library" is highly subjective and depends on personal preferences, existing know how, requirements of the work etc. etc.

While I prefer jQuery for (almost) everything, I know some people whio swear by Dojo or ExtJS. There might be case where you want to use jQuery but requirements might be dictate that you use ExtJS.

All said. Use jQuery. jQuery rocks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't really tie in with the client side. Use whatever you're comfortable with. Django plays well with everything in that area, because you just write it in the templates.