# Pass array from HTML to Django application

Tags: django

I developed an application in JSPs and Servlets involving drop down menus that kept growing with how many authors per publication their were.

This was done in JavaScript and then in my application iterated through them using a loop. Is this possible using Django? This would be useful in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link might help you out if you don't want to dive into javascript (too much)

http://www.dajaxproject.com/

Or have a look at this stackoverflow question/awnser:

[What is the best AJAX library for Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511843/what-is-the-best-ajax-library-for-django)

In any case, you need to serialize your array to a JSON string.
Then pass the JSON with an XMLHTTPRequest (ajax) to the server.

Add the javascript tag to your question if you don't mind more JS solutions.
Otherwise look for a Django Ajax framework to do the heavy lifting for you.